# How to save a list in a column to CSV?

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this.

[A column in dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCKm.png)

When I saved the dataframe to CSV, it looks like this.

[How it looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTf2g.png)

But I want it to look like this

[How it should look like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ue6.png)

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: do you just need to have the commas or do you also need each element of the list in a different row in excel?

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the array to a list:

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

example:

```
>>> df
             col1  col2
0  [test1, test2]  row1
>>> df['col1'][0]
array(['test1', 'test2'], dtype=object)
>>> df.to_csv('a.csv')
```

```
$ cat a.csv 
,col1,col2
0,['test1' 'test2'],row1
```

after applying the `list()`:

```
>>> df['col1']=df['col1'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
>>> df['col1'][0]
['test1', 'test2']
>>> df.to_csv('a.csv')
```

```
$ cat a.csv 
,col1,col2
0,"['test1', 'test2']",row1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a coma seperater while saving file
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
df.to_csv(filename,sep=',')
```